Проблема установки blueman в Astra Linux
На работе возникла проблема с Astra Linux, а если быть точнее, то с bluetooth. В чем суть: у нас имеются ноутбуки на базе Astra Linux Special Edition 1.7 (уровень защищенности: базовый) и для удобной работы необходимо подключать мультидатчики через bluetooth, но на этом этапе возникает проблема. Дело в том, что в данной операционной системе не установлен blueman(Насколько понимаю это "bluetooth"). Пробовал установить через Synaptic, но там ничего не отображается. Пробовал установить через cmd "sudo apt install blueman", тоже ничего. Точнее:

admin1@astra:~$ sudo apt install blueman
[sudo] пароль для admin1:
E: Не удалось получить файл блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Ресурс временно недоступен)
E: Невозможно получить блокировку внешнего интерфейса dpkg (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend); она уже используется другим процессом?<

Если использовать "sudo apt install blueman bluez" то следующее:

admin1@astra:~$ sudo apt install blueman bluez
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет blueman

Вообщем, перерыв оф.сайт Astra Linux увидел следующее:

Использование беспроводных устройств является небезопасным, и по возможности должно быть полностью исключено. Для установки пакета blueman в ОС Astra Linux Special Edition РУСБ.10015-01 (очередное обновление x.7) необходимо подключить расширенный репозиторий (см. Репозитории Astra Linux Special Edition x.7: структура, особенности подключения и использования), для более ранних очередных обновлений необходимо подключить репозиторий Astra Linux Common Edition.

А что подключать и как, ладу не могу дать, да и тем более лезть в систему как-то боязно. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, как быть и что делать?

Вам необходимо понять, какая версия оперативного обновления у вас установлена, потом подключить соответствующий расширенный репозиторий. https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=158598882
